# text file is not being opened for reading purposes

Tags: c++, c++17

Before you flag this as a duplicate post and refer me on how to correctly open a text file and print to the console, I have looked at numerous StackOverflow posts about this topic and cannot find a solution for myself.

I am trying to open a text file I created (currently in the same project folder as my main.cpp), read the text, and print it to the console. I go through the if file is open statement fine but the while loop does not go through even once. I will post the function below. Please suggest any changes or ideas on how to correctly call and open/read the text file. (and I would prefer not to call the exact file location of the text file for this to work ex. C://example/textFile.txt/ Though I have not tried this method yet, I'd prefer avoiding it)

Also, I am using CLion IDE from jetbrains, C++17, and Ninja to build.

> printing text file to console fucntion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "printTest.h"

void printTest::print() {
    std::string line; //string that holds the line of a text file
    std::ifstream textFile("test.txt", std::ios::in); //file creation

    if(textFile.is_open()) //checking if file was opened
    {
        while(std::getline(textFile, line))
        {
            //std::getline(textFile, line);
            std::cout << line << "\n";
        }
    } else { //this is always printing i.e. file is not correctly being opened for reading
        std::cout <<"Unable to open the text file..." <<std::endl; //Prints if file was not opened
    }
    textFile.close();
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you try using the full path. CLion may not be starting your app with the same working directory as the location of your source file.

Comment: "*currently in the same project folder as my main.cpp*" - is that the folder where the compiled `.exe` exists? Not all compilers/IDEs output the `.exe` in the same folder as the `.cpp` file(s). Where is the `.txt` file located in relation to the `.exe` file? "*I would prefer not to call the exact file location of the text file for this to work*" - but, does opening the file that way work correctly? If so, then most likely the program's working directory is not what you're expecting, since you are opening the file using a *relative* path rather than an *absolute* path.

Comment: Remember, the Operating System is at the heart of file opening and reading.  Opening files has little to do with the C++ language.  Try creating a file, writing something to it, then closing it.  Next, use the OS to find the file.

Comment: I'm almost certain that CLion being based on cmake does not set up or run anything from (one of) the source direcory(s). Add `std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path().string() << '\n';` to determine the working dir.

Comment: To create a minimal reproducible example, move all that code into `main` and thin out the redundant and irrelevant `#include` directives. That way people can actually compile and run your program instead of pretending they're a compiler and guessing at what the code might or might not do.